# MuleEvent Context to access the Payload in Mule 4

Tags: mule

I am trying to access the Payload in Mule 4 by using Mule Event Context api that we used in Mule 3.9. Could anyone please let me know how can it be accessed in Mule 4?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! To improve your experience, read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) an [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) question. You should also take a look at the [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). To lean more about how Stack Overflow works, [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 3):

You cannot access this in Mule 4 via Java components. The Mule4 SDK is now the only and canonical way of extending mule through java.

For more information on Mule SDK can be found here https://mule4-docs.mulesoft.com/mule-sdk/v/1.1/

You can also invoke Java classes but they need to be decoupled from the Mule API and you need to extract any variables, properties or payload  and explicitly pass the values to your class.
For example passing a static String and a flow var as arguments to a Java constructor:

```
<java:new class="com.foo.AppleEater" constructor="MyClass(String, Apple)">
  <java:args>#[{name: 'some string arg', apple: vars.apple}]</java:args>
</java:new>
```

More on Java integration with Mule 4 here: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.1/intro-java-integration